# Hashed variable changes on form submit

Tags: php, forms, session, spam-prevention

One technique I have been using to prevent form abuse is to add a hidden field that contains a hashed variable set at the server. When the form is submitted via AJAX to a PHP script it checks the POST value versus the value generated by a SESSION value.

In an include file at the beginning of all pages I have to generate the hash

```
$hashed_password = crypt($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],session_id());
$_SESSION['hashed_password'] = $hashed_password;
```

The form is sent via AJAX and the code there is;

```
    if ($_SESSION['hashed_password'] !== $_POST['thisname']) {
    // do stuff like show a message, record to a log, etc
    die();
}
```

Note: thisname is the name of the hidden field on the form.

This works beautifully 99.9% of the time. But, once in awhile they don't match. Not spammers either, regular customers. Seems to be mainly on Chrome.

I cannot see how this could be. A change in their IP address between delivering the form and submitting the form?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: IP address can easily change, especially if they're using phone

Comment: The session id can also change, if they close the browser and comeback.

Comment: What kind of abuse are you trying to prevent? A simple ReCaptcha may be what you need

Comment: Are you sure you want to store passwords in sessions?

Comment: ReCaptcha is not an option as most clients do not want it, and I agree. If you ever used a VPN, you would know how frustrating going through several rounds of verifications can be. It is not passwords, just a variable name.

If they closed the browser and came back, and new session ID would be generated.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile clients change their IP addresses frequently.

The http protocol is stateless. There is no guarantee that any two requests are related to each other.

On the flip side, you can easily get completely unrelated requests from a single IP.

Comment: OK, I have added some hidden fields on the form to check if they are in fact on a phone. Also, IP address at the form, and IP address on the form submit script. We'll see. May take a few days or a week. But, I can see mobile being the factor. I'll keep everyone posted. Thanks.

Comment: Quick update, on one website, it was Cloudflare that was the issue. Still waiting on a few other sites.

Answer (score 0):

Users may have your application open in multiple tabs. If you always have one and only one hash on the session, it's likely that they will submit with a previously valid hash that won't match the current one on the session. I handle this by keeping an array of the generated hashes on the session, each with a timestamp, and expire them after some period of time.